# Consume wsdl using wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I have one wsdl which is working fine on mule esb.
Now i  am new to wso2 i need to consume that wsdl via wso2.

I have tried to consume it from Wso2 developer studio but it showed 202 http status

Anyone can help me in this

The request of service is in xml with header APIKEY and username password basic authentication.

Anybody can help me in this problem.

Comment: Can you describe the issue with some sample code and screenshots?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><api context="/TEST" name="TEST" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><resource methods="POST">
<inSequence>
<property expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('xxxx:xxxx'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
<property name="APIKey" scope="default" type="STRING" value="xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"/><property name="POST_TO_URI" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/><send><endpoint>
<wsdl port="xxxxsoaphttp" service="xxxx" uri="https://xxxxx/1.0?wsdl"/>
</endpoint></send></inSequence><outSequence/><faultSequence/></resource></api>

Comment: @amg_amit The above comment is my code in eclipse developer studio

Comment: i see a ";" after wsdl tag, is that a typo. However have you tested the wsdl directly from SOAPUI to see if the web service is working or not

Comment: yes this is a typo error sorry for that. Yes from the SOAP UI its working fine even i developed this in MuleESB its working there now i am new to WO2 i have tried to make a proxy service for that and it showed me http status code 202

Comment: @amg_amit the code that i have mentioned in the comments showed me below error
Mediator encountered an error:The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is

Comment: EPR Not found is generally the operation which you are trying to access in the service is unavailable, can you check if you are calling the right operation

Comment: @amg_amit can you provide m sample source to consume a wsdl with username password authentication and the service is on https.

Comment: @amg_amit  it showed me 202 accepted
<proxy name="TEST2" startOnLoad="true" transports="https http" xmlns="http://xxxsynapse"><target><endpoint name="34xz"><wsdl port="xxx" service="xxx" uri="https://xxxx/1.0?wsdl"/></endpoint><inSequence><property expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('xxxx:xxxx'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/><property name="APIKey" scope="default" type="STRING" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/><property name="POST_TO_URI" scope="default" type="STRING"value="true"/></inSequence><outSequence><send/>

Comment: so you have set Authorization which looks fine but why do you have an empty <send> mediator, whenever you use send or call mediator you need to mention the URL of the service which you are calling, for better debugging i would recommend to start logging after every stage

Comment: @amg_amit ok so in outsequence send which endpoint i have to use http or address i tried it but still it showed 202 code furthermore in developer studio i am deploying at remote server as localserver not working

Comment: Move the send mediator to in sequence , you need to mention the endpoint of the service you are invoking in send mediator,use log mediator in out sequence to see if the call after send is going to out sequence or not.

Comment: @amg_amit I think copy pasting code here got remove i have send mediator in in-sequence with wsdlurl service port.

Answer (score 0):

I Chris, I am going to describe all the necessary steps to achieve what you want.

1. Create an WSDL Endpoint
2. Create a proxy, can be Custom Proxy.
   2.1 So, depending on what you want to do (get/post/...).
    For GET instance: You can Send the endpoint in (inSequence) and consume the response in outSequence with Payload factory ( https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/PayloadFactory+Mediator ) passing the necessary arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just wsdl endpoint whit proper configuration.